# How can I search by filename and filter by stars on Github?

Tags: github, github-api

According to the Github Advanced Search docs, you can [Query for values greater or less than another value](https://help.github.com/en/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-values-greater-or-less-than-another-value) using syntax like:

```
cats stars:>1000
```

This returns repositories with the word "cats" that have more than 1000 stars.

Also according to the Github Advanced Search guide for [Search by filename](https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-code#search-by-filename),

```
cats filename:package.json
```

This will return matches for the word "cats" inside the `package.json` file in repositories.

Given these two features (and possibly others I haven't mentioned here), I would like to search for specific files in repositories that have greater than a given number of stars.

```
plugin-syntax-dynamic-import filename:babel.config.js stars:>1000
```

This doesn't currently return the results I'm looking for - it returns matches for `plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` in `babel.config.js` but it also returns items with less than 1000 stars.

**How can I search by filename and filter by stars on Github?**